# Show full axis range for Plotly chart?

Tags: javascript, plotly

How can you show from 0,0 (or the lowest negative point) to 8,8 (or the highest data point) on the chart x,y while also showing the full chart?

```
var data = [
  {
    x: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];
var layout = {
  // autosize: true,
  // rangemode: "tozero",
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  autoscale: false,
  xaxis: { autorange: false },
  yaxis: { autorange: false },
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

If you enable autorange it shows the data, but not 0,0.

[image: with autorange on]

If you disable autorange it shows 0,0 but not the data.

[image: with autorange off]

Here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/Xeoncross/pen/MRREXq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the `rangemode` to `'tozero'` and enable `autorange` for each axis:

```js
var data = [
  {
    x: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];
var layout = {
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  autoscale: false,
  xaxis: { rangemode:'tozero', autorange:true},
  yaxis: { rangemode:'tozero', autorange:true}
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

See the [official Plotly examples](https://www.plot.ly/python/axes/#nonnegative-tozero-and-normal-rangemode).

Answer (score 3):

Your data is all there and showing it is just "hidden" because of the default zoom level. If you want all of the data points to show at once by default you can set a range in your x and y axis.

Also, setting a range will not affect your zooming in future uses.

Basically you can set the range min and max to be 0 and your highest value.

```
xaxis: { autorange: false, range:[0, 10]},
yaxis: { autorange: false, range:[0, 10]},
```

In the following snippet I made two variables to track the x and y max and add 2. This will ensure there is a buffer of 2 on the top to show all of the data points.

```js
var data = [
  {
    x: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];

var xMax = data[0].x[data[0].x.length - 1] + 2;
var yMax = data[0].y[data[0].y.length - 1] + 2;
var layout = {
  // autosize: true,
  // rangemode: "tozero",
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  autoscale: false,
  xaxis: { autorange: false, range:[0, xMax]},
  yaxis: { autorange: false, range:[0, yMax]},
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: While working, I would expect the library authors to provide some sort of auto-scale functionality without requiring manual setting of the min-max range. I have to leave this question open for a while anyway, so maybe someone will provide a setting we missed.